# result table description

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query in SQL. Can someone help me for writing oracle sql query for below result table

```
Table 1 Data
prodno  description
1   Laptop
2   Charger
3   Mouse

Table 2 Data 
prodno  prodset_no
1   1   
2   1
3   1
1   2
3   2
1   3
2   3


Result Table
prodset_no  prodset_desc
1       Laptop,Charger,Mouse
2       Laptop,Mouse
3       Laptop,Charger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the two table and then use `listagg` to produce comma separated output:

```
select t2.prodset_no,
    listagg(t1.description, ',') within group (
        order by t1.prodno
        ) prodset_desc
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.prodno = t1.prodno
group by t2.prodset_no;
```

Also, worth a note that the `listagg` has a limit of 4000 bytes. If you hit that limit, you can either use `XMLAGG` or rethink the problem and not do it in SQL at all but rather handle it in your application code.